# Dask: Dataframe to_dask_array not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to create dask array from dask dataframe as below:

---

input.csv

A, B, C

5, 7, 8

9, 6, 11

15, 3, 2

0, 1, 5

2, 4, 3

---

```
df1 = dd.read_csv('input.csv')
print(type(df1))
print(df1.head())
arr = df1.values # working good
print(type(arr))
print(arr.compute())

arr2 = df1.to_dask_array(lengths=True) # (Not working) I want to Specify lengths=True which can triggers immediate computation of the chunk sizes.
print(type(arr2))
```

---

Output:

```
C:\Anaconda\python.exe C:/App.py
<class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'>
    A   B   C
0   5   7   8
1   9   6  11
2  15   3   2
3   0   1   5
4   2   4   3
<class 'dask.array.core.Array'>
[[ 5  7  8]
 [ 9  6 11]
 [15  3  2]
 [ 0  1  5]
 [ 2  4  3]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/App.py", line 68, in <module>
    arr2 = df1.to_dask_array(lengths=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py", line 2313, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError("'DataFrame' object has no attribute %r" % key)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_dask_array'
```

Comment: can you try with lengths=False

Comment: Do you mind to share your `dask.__version__`? I'm using `2.2.0` and I don't receive this error.

Comment: @rpanai yes it was version issue, its resolved Thanks all for your inputs